# emulator stopped working after starting once

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity

i have created a AVD,it starts normally asking for "Connect to charger" and then it stops working.Unable to understand the problem.please help

Comment: Dont the the emulator. Use Genymotion or your own device. Just a tip:)

Comment: hope this work..still i want my emulator to work..what should i do..?
m having pentium(D). Is there a processor issue..?

Comment: I only have bad experiences with the built in emulator. I strongly suggest using Genymotion, which runs as a virtual machine, or on your own device.

Comment: same problem in Genymotion..it stops working :(

Answer (score 0):

You need to set a sufficient memory for your emulator in the AVD settings, try to update if you didn't and as suggested use genymotion which is a good alternative, if your using eclipse try out Android studio